# CSV file where data contains comma and quotation mark - R

Tags: r, csv

Clarification - I have an R program that pulls data from Twitter.  This includes the tweet, which I keep in variable text.  I want to be able to store the data in CSV files, to examine in excel. This has been fine, until recently where I've hit tweets with people who USE commas.  Those tweets then break the format.

Trying to store data into excel.  One cell contains text.

Let's say my cells are

```
 age      text      arbitraryCount
```

My text is :

```
    @AmyMek: Christians burn while the pope worries about "Climate Change"! Meanwhile, @realDonaldTrump defends persecuted Christians! #GOPD
```

So I hope to get the output

```
    age,text,arbitraryCount
    21, @AmyMek: Christians burn while the pope worries about "Climate Change"! Meanwhile, @realDonaldTrump defends persecuted Christians! #GOPD,12
```

Instead what I get is

```
   age
   21
```

Which is correct, but

```
  text
  RT @AmyMek: Christians burn while the pope worries about \Climate Change\"! Meanwhile

  arbitraryCount
   @realDonaldTrump defends persecuted Christians! #GOPD…"
```

Which is not correct.

What causes this problem, and is there an easy way to alleviate it?  Perhaps some processing I should be doing to my "text" as I pull it in?

How I am creating the CSV file :

```
    write.table(finalDataFrame, paste(path, queryName, "_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep=""), na="NA", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

What "finalDataFrame" is?

```
        finalDataFrame = data.frame( var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7,text,var8,var9,var10 )
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you using R or Excel? How are you "getting" these values? What code are you running?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it matters how I get the values.
I have an R program that pulls data from Twitter.  This includes the tweet.  I want to be able to store the data in CSV files, to examine in excel. This has been fine, until recently where I've hit tweets with people who USE commas.  Those tweets then break the format.

Comment: How are you creating the CSV file? Are you explicitly disabling the quoting of the strings? If you want help with code, you should show us some code.

Comment: Editted in my output and what my data.frame that I am writing to the CSV file looks like.

Comment: Use `write.csv` rather than `write.table`. That should quote the strings by default. YOu need to have your test wrapped in quotes otherwise commas in the text mess everything up.

Comment: The issue with that, is I am trying to use "append".  I originally intended to use write.csv, but when I do, append=TRUE does not work.  I want this functionality, is this not possible to do AND get the quote protection that write.csv offers?

Comment: You can add `quote=TRUE` to `write.table`. Feel free to read the `?read.table` help page to understand what's going on.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I appreciate the help, but using write.table() with quote=TRUE did nothing differently unfortunately :/